# Referrer persists when I refresh the page. Why isn't it clared?

Tags: http, http-referer, request-headers

On the website I'm working cart page and checkout page are part of a single page app.

And we have this scenario:

1. User is on product page.
2. Adds the product to cart - and then he/she lands on cart page.
3. After that user proceeds to checkout page.
4. And then, if we refresh the page - the document.referrer points to the product page. (The page before cart and checkout.)

And this is problematic, cause we have logic for that which shouldn't execute after the refresh.

I noticed that when we refresh the checkout page - the `Referer` request header is set and I guess that's the problem. But why is it set? ... Shouldn't this `Referrer` header get cleared after user navigates away from product page?

(This happens on Chrome and Safari, it doesn't happen on Firefox.)

EDIT:

I narrowed down the things to two simple pages:

1. page1.html has only a button. When clicked on it - I make `location.href = 'page2.html'`.
2. page2.html - there I simply show the `document.referrer`.

So - when I go to page2.html - referrer is page2.html. But when I refresh page2.html - referrer is STILL page1.html.

Why is that? Shouldn't it be blank or page2.html ?

Comment: How does user "land on cart page" and "proceed to checkout page"? POST, GET, location.href=, location.replace(), ...?

Comment: After adding the product we navigate with JS - `location.href='/cart'`. From cart to checkout - user clicks a button where we call `navigate` method of our router. It is based on Backbone router. And also we use hash based routing, if that matters.

Comment: Then it sounds like whatever magic your router uses to `navigate` is maintaining the headers from the previous page.

Comment: I wonder how this could happen at all. Because when we refresh the page - we use the built in browser's functionality. So my initial guess was that the browser was doing something behind the scene. ... When I refresh a page - the browser itself is what sends the `Referer` request header, no?

Comment: I don't know because it's a long time since I even thought about low-level browser mechanics, and a lot has changed since I did, but have you considered using href to go to checkout instead of making your router interfere? (e.g. you're asking "why is router.navigate not working like href?" when you could be asking "why are we using router.navigate instead of href?")

Comment: Thank you, @AaronBertrand - I just updated my question with a super basic variant of the problem. And so - is this expected? ... Cause for me it doesn't make sense ...

Comment: I think you meant `when I go to page2.html - referrer is page**1**.html`, I don't believe refresh a page adds a step in its history (e.g. `history.go(-1)` will still go to `page1.html`, right?) so I'm not sure why you expect refresh to update the page headers and add a history item that isn't valid? Can you explain why you want the referrer to be the current page after a refresh?

Comment: Well - the use case is that the new page is single page app, so when user navigates inside it - then the referrer should get cleared. Cause we have logic based on the referrer and if/when user refreshes the page - this logic shouldn't trigger.

Comment: But I don't think the browser is designed to support your specific implementation of single-page app, so... I'm not sure I can offer any further assistance.